# I want to put number on a image dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I want to put number on a image dynamically.

Comment: it would help you, if you can be more specific and provide examples of code you have tried

Comment: And if you phrase it as a question..

Comment: are you trying to watermark a number on an image dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Take two div's. Set backgroung image for one div and put some number on another div. Place the second div on first div by using css properties like position, z-index

Comment: What's the problem with one div ?

Comment: If we use 2 div's we can place the number where ever we want but it is some what difficult with a single div.

Comment: No, it isn't. Handle your element as block and positioned absoluted.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing that:

1.) In the client-side:
You can use the HTML5 CANVAS API. This API allows you to draw arbitrary shapes and images inside a canvas element that is rendered into the browser. So to solve your problem you could load an image inside the canvas and after that draw a number on top of it.

2.) In the server-side:
You will load the image and after that draw the number inside of it using a server-side application. Eg. an application developed using PHP, ASP.NET, Python, etc. In PHP you can use the GD library to do that.